# WordPress $wpdb Insert and Update not working

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am using a MySQL query from inside a WordPress custom plugin. I am submitting two values when posting. I want to update the time column if the user exists in the database.

Here is my code

```
function main()
{
  if (isset($_REQUEST)) {

    global $wpdb;
    $taskTime = $_REQUEST["task_current_time"];
    $taskTitle = $_REQUEST["task_current_title"];

    $select_all_current = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $this->tablenamev2 WHERE task_current_title = '$taskTitle'");

    if ($wpdb->get_results($select_all_current)) {

      var_dump("USER EXIST");

      $wpdb->prepare("UPDATE $this->tablenamev2 SET task_current_time = '$taskTime' WHERE task_current_title = '$taskTitle'");

      return;
    } else {

      var_dump("USER DOES NOT EXIT!!!");

      $wpdb->query("INSERT INTO $this->tablenamev2 (task_current_time, task_current_title) VALUES ('$taskTime', '$taskTitle')");

      die();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/ prepare only prepares the query, it doesn't execute it. You wrap the prepare in the query method.

Answer (score 1):

The mistake was in $select_all_current = $wpdb->prepare() and instead I replaced it with $wpdb->query();

Thank you for ur help!

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code for update and insert(hope it helps)....

```
function main()
{
  if (isset($_REQUEST)) {

    global $wpdb;
$table_px = $this->tablenamev2;
// Hope tablenamev2 is the table name.....

    $taskTime = $_REQUEST["task_current_time"];
    $taskTitle = $_REQUEST["task_current_title"];

    $select_all_current = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $this->tablenamev2 WHERE task_current_title = '$taskTitle'");

    if ($wpdb->get_results($select_all_current)) {

      var_dump("USER EXIST");

      $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( "
        UPDATE `%s` SET  `task_current_time` = %s WHERE `task_current_title` = %s )",
       $table_px, $taskTime, $taskTitle
    ) );  

      return;
    } else {

      var_dump("USER DOES NOT EXIT!!!");

$data = array('task_current_time' => $taskTime, 'task_current_title' => $taskTitle);
$format = array('%s','%s');
$wpdb->insert($table_px,$data,$format);


      die();
    }
```

Let me know if it working..

Comment: Hi and thank you for ur reply. No its not working.

Comment: Are you sure `$this->tablenamev2` has this format :
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix.'you_table_name'; and another clarification, is wpdb-> results is working correctly ?